# Read expression using fgets and get the numeric values using sscanf

Tags: c, fgets, scanf

I have to do a program which reads an RPN (Reverse Polish Notation) expression and then evaluates it.

For reading the expression I have to use fgets. And then for get the numeric values of this expression I have to use sscanf. Input and output will be done using STDIN and STDOUT.

The idea is to read something like that:

```
5 2 pi cos - 4 * + 3 -
```

And then save this expression into `m x 2` matrix.

I can read a number (float or not), a constant (like `pi`), an operator (like `+ or - or /`) or a function (like `sin or cos`).

While I'm readind every character of the expression I have to store this information into the matrix, and if I have a number i will set it at the position `matrix[0][k], where k is not important`, if I have constant it will go at the position `matrix[1][k], k is not important`, operator in `matrix[2][k], k is not important` and function in `matrix[3][k]`.

So the before expression will be like this:

`{{0,5},{0,2},{1,0},{3,2},{2,1},{0,4},{2,2},{2,0},{0,3},{2,1}}.`

I have to do this in C, and I am facing some problems. The main problem is to get the values of the expression entered by user. I have this:

```
int main() {

// Cadena de caracteres donde guardamos la expresion rpn
char str[MAX];

int matrix[MAX][2];
int i = 0; 

printf("Enter a string: ");
// Cogemos los 100 caracteres que haya por consola, controlando errores
if(fgets(str, 100, stdin) == NULL) printf("Error leyendo por consola");

/* Si hay un salto de linea lo borramos */
i = strlen(str)-1;
if( str[ i ] == '\n') str[i] = '\0';

converteix_codis(matrix, str, i);

// Creamos la pila
pila p;
// Inicializamos la pila
initStack(&p);

int a = avalua_rpn(matrix, &p);

// Comprobar si se ha podido evaluar el rpn o no
printf("avalua = %d\n", a);

printf("This is your string: %s\n", str);

return 0;   
}


void converteix_codis(int matriu[MAX][2], char str[MAX], int i)
{
    int tamanyo = 0;

int j, k = 0;
int nombres = 0, constants = 0, operacions = 0, funcions = 0; 
char a[3] = "";
for(j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
    // Si el caracter que leemos es un digito
    if(isdigit(str[j])) {
        matriu[0][nombres] = (int) str[j];
        ++nombres;
        ++tamanyo;
    }
    // Si el caracter que leemos es una operacion
    else if(ispunct(str[j])) {
        int num;
        if(str[j] == '+') num = 0;
        else if(str[j] == '-') num = 1;
        else if(str[j] == '*') num = 2;
        else if(str[j] == '/') num = 3;
        else if(str[j] == '^') num = 4;
        matriu[2][operacions] = num;
        ++operacions;
        ++tamanyo;
    }

}
}
```

In the function `converteix_codis` I am trying to store this information, but I don't know how to get the strings `sin, cos, pi, e and others` for storing them into the matrix. With operations and digits I tried that, but if I have a float it won't read it ok. Any suggestions about how to use fgets and sscanf to read this? (I have to use them because is a requeriment).

Thank you a lot!

Comment: Use integers instead of strings. For example, `#define SIN 1` and store SIN instead of the `sin` string

Comment: The problem is that input must be like that `5 2 pi cos - 4 * + 3 -` because it is the user who enters it

Comment: I mean, after reading `sin` i store the value 0, not `sin` value, but first I have to read the sin string, do you understand?

Comment: You should understand that external representation (`sin`, `cos`, `pi`, etc.) and stored data do not have to be the same. You should store codes of the possible strings (function and constant names) but read and print them as strings.

Comment: That's why I am doing. I'm reading `sin` value, but I am storing them with codes. But anyway that's not the problem. The problem is how to read the data from expression entered by user. I don't know how to split it.

Comment: you should change `(int ) str[j]` for something like `atoi(strj)`, casting a char to int will not parse it

Comment: I was just trying, that's not the problem, but thanks. Anyway in this case was a digit, but if it would be a float, how should I proceed?

Comment: Have you looked at `strtok()`? (http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok)

Comment: I'm supposed to do this using only fgets to read the input of user. sscanf to get the numeric values of the input, and strcmp to get the no numeric values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Examples of splits and numerical decision(Easy way, not rigorous way).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool isNumber(const char *str, double *num){
    char *endp;
    double n = strtod(str, &endp);
    if(*endp == '\0'){
        *num = n;
        return true;
    }
    *num = NAN;
    return false;
}

int main(void){
    char str[] = "5 2 pi cos - 4 * + 3 -";
    char *token;
    double n;

    token = strtok(str, " \t\n");
    while(token){
        if(isNumber(token, &n)){//if(1==sscanf(token, "%lf%c", &n, &ch)){//char ch;
            printf("%g\n", n);
        } else {
            printf("%s\n", token);
        }
        token = strtok(NULL, " \t\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using `sscanf` is a requirement

Comment: `if(isNumber(token)){ sscanf(token, "%lf", &n);  printf("%g\n", n);`

Comment: What is ridiculous?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `fgets` in order to read the operation as you as doing, and then `sscanf` and an auxiliary pointer in order to divide the given string into his elements. It would look something like this

```
            #include <stdio.h>
            #include <string.h>
            void main(){
                char str[100];
                char str2[100];

                char * aux; 

                int i, counter, len;
                printf("Introduce operation: ");
                fgets(str,100,stdin);
                strtok(str, "\n"); // Eliminate line jump
                len = strlen(str);
                for (i =0 ,counter =0; i<len ; i++)
                    if (str[i] == ' ') counter ++;  

                aux = str;
                for (i=0; i<counter + 1 ; i++){
                    sscanf(aux, "%s", str2);
                    printf("Element: %s" , str2);
                    aux = str + strlen(str2)* sizeof(char);
                }


            }
```

The parsing is not included here. Also some improvements can be made (in order to eliminate the first loop for example). This code purpose is mainly to give you an idea of how you could use `sscanf`

**Edit:** If the space needs to be eliminated:

```
aux = str + (strlen(str2) + 1) * sizeof(char)
```

Comment: `aux = str + strlen(str2)* sizeof(char);` : Space character isn't taken into consideration.

Comment: And `str + strlen(str2)` : Position is not continued.

Comment: Didn't understand that last one. Could you be more clear?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY any idea?

Comment: @MohamedSaidBenmousa use `strtok`.

Comment: How can I use it? Regarding to this problem I thought one thing, i can iterate the string I read, and do something like: `if(isdigit(str[j])) { and here do something like while(!isspace(str[j]))` store the digits in a buffer (using strcat), and then convert it to double with `atof`. What do you think?

Comment: @MohamedSaidBenmousa use `strtod` for check number

Comment: Using `strtok` is very useful, and it is the easier solution. But if using `sscanf` is mandatory, we can use an auxiliary pointer  and `sscanf` to substitute `strtok`